# How do I start a list on the second level?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I am using the `enumerate` environment, and I want to have my lists start on 1.1. instead of 1., and 2.1. instead of 2. How can I hide the first level?

Comment: Typically the first number denotes the first level; the second number denotes the second level; and so on. So you want to *reverse* this. In your example, what does the `1` in `2.1` represent? Chapter number? Section number? Or just some fixed value?

Comment: I want to answer the questions in a tutorial. There are two questions with a number of sub-questions each. I want the first thing that appears after the title to just be "1.1." instead of "1." So, I still want the "1." to be there in the code, I just want to hide it.

Comment: \savebox can be used to hide things and (globally) increment counters.

Comment: @John How do I use savebox? By putting `\savebox\item` when I want to hide that point?

Comment: \newsavebox{\myname} in the preamble and \savebox{\myname}{...}.  I would leave the \begin{enumerate} outside and only put individual \items inside.  (BTW, I haven't actually tested this on \items.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the numbering locally by using the optional argument to `\item[..]`, or use a global change using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `label=<key>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.1.}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third

  % Done with the 1. suffix; revert back to regular enumerate labelling
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1.1.] First

  \stepcounter{enumi}
  \item Second

  \item[2.2.] Third

  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\item`-level changes are also possible, like in the first example above, where the labelling mechanism can be changed mid-`enumerate` to drop (say) the `1.` suffix.

Note that using the optional argument to `\item` doesn't step the level counter `enumi`.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a mix with manipulation the enumeration depth counter and `enumitem` and sets the `higher` level counter `enumi` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{enumerate}{%
  \global\@enumdepth 0
}

\newcommand{\incenumdepth}[1][1]{%
  \advance \@enumdepth \@ne%
  \setcounter{enum\@roman{\@enumdepth}}{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\incenumdepth[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label*={\arabic*.}]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\end{enumerate}

\incenumdepth[3]
\begin{enumerate}[label*={\arabic*.}]
\item One \makeatletter \the\@enumdepth\makeatother
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]